# Intellij idea hotkey to open context menu of a file

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey combination to open the context menu on a file in the project tree (instead of mouse right click) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On Windows, you can use the dedicated "context menu" key to the right of the spacebar. On other operating systems, there is no default shortcut, but you can assign one if you search for "Show context menu" in Settings | Keymap.

Comment: Most latest compact laptops have eliminated to dedicated context menu button. `Shift`+`F10` doesnt work as desired.

Comment: The "context menu" key also works on KDE Neon out of the box.

Comment: Setting a shortcut via Settings | Keymap was the only way it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On `Windows` / `*nix`, you can use `Alt + Insert` to open context menu in a project tree.
Currently I'm looking for a shortcut for mac :)

UPD: On Mac it is `Control^ + Enter`